# Swift Prevent Emoji Representation of Unicode Character

Tags: swift, unicode, emoji

I want to print the unicode character `U+21A9` which is the undo arrow (↩), but Apple likes to turn that in a bubbly looking emoji like [image: undo arrow emoji]

Comment: My unverified understanding is that you can use the text variation selector by writing `\u21a9\ufe0e` instead of just `\u21a9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick a font containing the glyph that you want, like Lucida Grande or Menlo.